# Build shortcut for `traceback.format_exc()`

Tags: python, python-3.x, shortcut

So I use `traceback.format_exc()` like this:

```
try:
   # Some code
except:
   traceback_msg = '%s' % traceback.format_exc()
   print(traceback_msg)
   # Doing some stuff with it
```

pretty often in my code to output it to an additional file/stream and by writing code I am tired to keep typing it. Is there a simple way to define a global shortcut/ExceptionHandler which keeps care and is easy to call from various places?

Comment: Well, you could do `tfe = traceback.format_exc` globally, then `print(tfe())` wherever you need it.

Comment: Can you clarify what is your criteria for a shortcut? You can do this with one import per file and one line per use (there is no need for the string formatting). The module also has ``traceback.print_exc``, which evens aces the ``print`` call. How much shorter than this should a shortcut be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a module in a directory `PYTHONPATH` that imports under a shortened name (and itself has a short name).

In your setup script set environment variable `PYTHONPATH` to point to a directory, e.g. in `.bashrc` in Linux, put

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/my_dir:$PYTHONPATH
```

(You might want to do a test if any value already exists, and if not, suppress the colon here, but it's not critical.)

and also create `/path/to/my_dir/tb.py` containing

```
from traceback import format_exec as fe
```

Then you could do interactively e.g.:

```
>>> import tb
>>> try:
...    a = 1 / 0
... except:
...    msg = tb.fe()
...    print(">>>", msg)
```

to give

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Bear in mind though that your `tb.py` could conflict with another module also called `tb.py` that you are trying to use.  Maybe for safety don't set `PYTHONPATH` all the time, but then (again Linux example here), set up an alias in your `.bashrc`.

`alias p='env PYTHONPATH=/path/to/my_dir:$PYTHONPATH python'`

so that it is only set when you launch python with the `p` alias.

There is also an environment variable `PYTHONSTARTUP` which you can point at a script that runs whenever you start python, although not used in this example.

Comment: `from traceback import format_exec as fe` and simply `fe()` in the exception does the trick without defining a python file in the path and having the danger of overwriting `tb.py`. Thanks.

Comment: @gies0r Yes clearly so, I just wasn't sure whether the long import statement was part of the typing that you wanted to avoid.

Comment: Got a global file in all of my scripts for such things already (to put that in), but nice that you pointed it out. Accepted.